# Comparar valores de listas en Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo la siguiente pregunta. 
Supongamos que el usuario ingresó 2,3,4,5 y creo el array [2,3,4,5] eso va a dar un output de "Los valores son iguales".

Mi duda es, si tengo en el input [3,2,5,4] como puedo hacer que me siga retornando "Los valores son iguales" ya que siguen siendo los mismos valores pero en diferente orden.

Saludos y gracias.
El código es el siguiente:

```
introducir el código aquí
lista = [2,3,4,5]
lista2 = []

#creación de lista2 por input 
   for i in range(4):
      valor= int(input("Ingresa valor: ")) 
      lista2.append(valor)

#Comparar listas
if lista2 == lista:
   print("Los valores son iguales")
else:
   print("Los valores no son iguales"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si el concepto de igualdad que manejas, es que ambas listas tengan los mismos elementos y las mismas cantidades de ellos, lo que puedes hacer es comparar ambas, pero ordenadas:

```
if sorted(lista2) == sorted(lista):
```

Con [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) retornas la lista con el orden natural aplicable, en este caso, que son enteros, numérico ascendentes.

Comment: Perfecto, solucionó el problema que se tenía. Gracias @Patricio Moracho.

Comment: Si te ha solucionado el problema, puedes agradecerselo aceptando su respuesta (haciendo clic en el tick verde que hay bajo la puntuación de su respuesta). Con esto indicas a futuros usuarios que esa respuesta es la que soluciona ese problema concreto.